# Check If Database Was Created Successfully

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can I check whether or not my application's database was created successfully?

Answer (score 2):

A `SQLiteException` is thrown if an error occurs in `openDatabase()`.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)